# Does SQL guarantee that `SELECT *` in a subquery will be optimized to prevent a full scan?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am exploring extended events query tracking and have question on couple of odd queries like following:

Example 1:

```
select top 10  *   from   (   SELECT [id]       ,[date]       ,[ordnum]       ,
[customer]  ,[amt]   ,[gm pc]   FROM [DbName].[dbo].[tblSales]  ) as [_]
where [date]>='2022-01-01T00:00:00.000'
```

Example 2:

```
select [_].[id],      [_].[date],   [_].[ordnum],  [_].[customer], [_].[amt], 
[_].[gm pc]  
from   (  SELECT [id] ,[date] ,[ordnum] ,  [customer]  ,[amt]  ,[gm pc]   
FROM [DbName].[dbo].[tblSales]  ) as [_]  where [_].[date] >= 
convert(datetime2, '2020-01-01 00:00:00') 
    and [_].[date] < convert(datetime2, '2021-01-01 00:00:00')
```

So in the subquery it selects all rows. And then in outer query it applies the where criteria.

If it literally works like this then it means the subquery will do the full table scan and then apply the where clause to the result. Or does this query gets optimized so that the where clause is applied directly on the table?

Comment: Are you asking practically or theoretically?

Comment: Practically how it runs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The SQL text expresses the *logical* results needed. SQL Server's cost-based optimizer finds an efficient *physical* way of implementing that *logical* requirement. The results are guaranteed to be the same (for all possible data values) as specified by the SQL, of course.

One of the basic things the optimizer does is to push filtering conditions (predicates) as far down (toward the leaves of) the execution plan as possible.

So yes, for all practical purposes, examples like yours are 'guaranteed' not to execute literally with a full scan followed by a filter. The filtering condition will normally be evaluated as part of the scan, or better yet as an index range seek if a suitable index is available.

> If it literally works like this then it means the subquery will do the full table scan and then apply the where clause to the result.

You still seem to be thinking of execution plans as if each operator executes to completion before passing the resulting rows to the next operator. *It does not work that way*. See my article [Iterators, Query Plans, and Why They Run Backwards](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/iterators-query-plans-and-why-they-run-backwards.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

While it has some procedural elements, the heart of SQL is the query which is declarative (often stated as sql being a declarative language).

That means the SQL engine decides how to fulfill your request.  As an analogy, you tell it you would like a hamburger, you don’t tell it when to flip the burger or how to make the patty.

As long as the answer/action is correct, how is considered irrelevant.  Of course everything else being equal, people would naturally prefer an engine that answers faster, so the engine takes the query, looks at what it knows about the database and tries to pick the best method all things considered.

That includes things like caching the results, using indexes and yes, moving predicates around.

Theoretically there is a defined order for each operation, practically speaking, everything is optional and can be done (or not) in any order as long as the result is correct.

For example, if your where clause predicate says not null, but the column is itself not null, that check can be removed entirely, it is satisfied when the query plan is being built. Or a left join might be turned into an inner join because the where clause says that the join column is not null or even a specific value.